# Google Maps InfoWindow. How to copy the content to clipboard?

Tags: copy, maps, infowindow, onmouseover

This is probably a stupid question. I am using the google maps InfoWindow to display some text whenever i hover above certain places (onmouseover). I'd like to be able to copy the text that gets displayed. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: i really face this from few days, in before it works correctly but in few days it does not works, no code change and anything, Have any update about this? Have you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a div with a CSS `style="user-select: text !important"` inside the content block of the info window.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content : "<div class='infowindow-content' style='user-select: text !important'>Your content goes inside here...`enter code here`
               </div>"
});
```